# Why are some videos HTML5 and some Flash - and how do I force HTML5?

Tags: youtube, flash, html5

When I watch [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqnB2Ew0SFM&feature=BFa&list=WL2AA75EB885F2A4B4) it's in Flash.

But when I click on [this other video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LD3ywXEydyk) - that video is in HTML5.

Why are some videos in Flash and some in HTML5? Also how can I force HTML5 for videos (for example, when I want to use the speed-up feature)?

Comment: More strange example, and updating to 2014: a [VEVO's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAqZb52sgpU) need Flash, many other (like [this other copyrighted video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9yWv5dqSKk)) not need;  using Firefox 29 with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the first example is that you are not going straight to the video. Instead of watching as part of a playlist, view the video only: 
**[`http://youtu.be/KqnB2Ew0SFM`](http://www.youtu.be/KqnB2Ew0SFM)**

This is the full URL:  **[`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqnB2Ew0SFM`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqnB2Ew0SFM)** Now you'll get all the features supported by HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by changing the URL with *any* video.

Simply take the video id (like the `KqnB2Ew0SFM` above in the 1st answer

and add it after this: `http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=`

(getting `http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=KqnB2Ew0SFM` if using that video)

This way, the video takes up your whole screen and is forced to play in HTML5 (well, just make sure you're in the HTML5 player trial to begin with, if you aren't already...you can opt-in by going to www.youtube.com/html5)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers don't work for me, however switching my user agent to iPad/Safari will enable HTML5 playback.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @serenesat no it shouldn't. It answers the question. Answers don't belong in comments.